# 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'app.register.service') when using requirejs, angularamd and karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner, angular-amd

In our angularjs project, we are using requirejs + angularAMD to manage dependencies. The application works fine, but we're having problems when running the jasmine tests using karma.

This is the error:

```
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'app.register.service')
  at /home/bcatarino/Projects/spr/target-grunt/js/app/model/PressRelease.js:3
```

It seems that our app is not correctly injected into our test.

The source code for the test:

```
'use strict';

define(['angularAMD', 'pressRelease'], function(angularAMD, pressRelease) {

    describe('PressReleaseModel test', function () {

        var scope, pressReleaseModel;

        var inject = angularAMD.inject;

        inject(function (pressRelease) {
            pressReleaseModel = pressRelease;
        });


        it('Should add a non-existing recipient', function(pressRelease) {
            expect(pressReleaseModel.get().recipients.length, 0);
        });
    });
});
```

PressRelease is coded like this:

```
define([ 'app', 'angularAMD' ], function(app, angularAMD) {

    app.register.service('pressRelease', function() {

    //Stuff going on here

    } );

});
```

So this is where `app.register` is undefined and we can't figure out why.

As requested, here's the karma.conf:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../../../',
        files: [
            {pattern: 'js_components/angular/angular.js', watched: false, included: false},
            {pattern: 'js_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'js_components/angularAMD/angularAMD.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'js_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'js_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'js/test/test-app.js', watched: true, included: false},
            {pattern: 'js/app/model/PressRelease.js', watched: true, included: false},
            {pattern: 'js/test/model/PressReleaseModelSpec.js', watched: true, included: false},
            'js_components/requirejs/require.js',
            'js/test/test-main.js'
        ],
        exclude: [],
        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-requirejs'
        ],
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'karma-test-results.xml',
            suite: ''
        },
        port: 9876,
        runnerPort: 9100,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],
        autoWatch: true,
        preprocessors: {
            'template/**/*.html': ['html2js']
        },
        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            // strip this from the file path
            stripPrefix: 'web',
            moduleName: 'templates'
        },
        logLevel : config.LOG_INFO
    })
};
```

Anyone has any ideas? We're following this as example, but we're not finding the answer:
https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show your karma.conf.js file

Comment: Edited to add karma.conf.file. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing AngularAMD from unit tests. I created a bridge that redirects `app.register.method` to `app.method` where `app` is an Angular module.

```
define([
    'angularMocks',
    'angular'
], function () {
    'use strict';
    var myapp = angular.module('SPR', []);

    myapp.register = {};
    var enhanceModule = function (method) {
        var register = myapp.register;
        register[method] = angular.bind(myapp, myapp[method]);
    };

    angular.forEach([
        'controller',
        'directive',
        'filter',
        'factory',
        'service',
        'constant',
        'value',
        'animation']
    , enhanceModule);

    console.info('Enhanced angular.module');
    return angular.module('SPR');
});
```

This is the test:

```
define(['angularMocks', 'app', 'js/app/model/PressRelease'], function (mocks) {

    describe('Press Release model', function () {

        var service;
        beforeEach(mocks.module('SPR'));
        beforeEach(mocks.inject(function (PressRelease) {
            service = PressRelease;
        }));

        it('should do something', function () {
            var res = service.serviceCall();
            expect(res).toBe(1);
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I never managed to get ngScenario to work with angularAMD.  I had to use [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor), the new standard for AngularJS E2E testing, for angularAMD.

Here is the Protractor spec file:
https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD/blob/master/test/e2e/www.spec.js

You can also find some more detail about E2E testing and angularAMD at:
https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD/issues/20

The Travis is reporting build failure right now but the test runs fine in my local machine.

Comment: In this case we want to unit test a simple angular service (not e2e testing). I'm new to js testing frameworks, but the way I understand it, protractor is not meant for unit testing. Anyway, the link you provided seems to confirm that there's some code being run before all the necessary dependencies are loaded

Comment: `app.register` is only available after you call `angularAMD.bootstrap(app)` and therefore is normally only used in E2E testing.  Hopefully future version of angularAMD would remove this requirement but for now you need to use Protractor.

Comment: I do call angularAMD.bootstrap, but it seems to be some asynchronous loading here and bootstrap is only called after trying to call app.register. If I force to call bootstrap in my test, I get the error saying that I can only do it once (which means the first time is actually called, just too late for it to work properly). Looking forward for that improvement! Thanks